# multiscript document replaces Latin character with Japanese character in print

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, printing, business-cards

I made a business card with Japanese and English text. 
Then I gave it to "printing service". They could view the pdf and saw no mistakes but the printer *A* replaced a latin character with a japanese dot.
The mistake is in an email address of all places, which I can't publish but this should do:

```
\node[rectangle, draw=none, anchor=center, align=left, scale=1.1] at (x,y) {ほげほげ、 \\ ホゲホゲ何に何に。 \\[2mm] foofoo@asbaba-ba.ba \\[1mm] link };
```

[image]

There are some problems: I cannot print on *A* myself, maybe one more time and on my (paper) printer B I can't reproduce it. Therefore I can't make a MWE.

I believe this version contains everything needed to reproduce on some printers

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[portrait, paperwidth=50mm,paperheight=30mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[rectangle, align=left] at (0,0) {ほげほげ、 \\ ホゲホゲ何に何に。 \\[2mm] foofoo@asbaba-ba.ba \\[1mm] link};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

The original contains more pictures and a second page, I'll post it if needed.

My current fix is to convert to jpg:

```
convert -density 600 -background white -alpha remove jbc.pdf jbc.jpg
```

but I would prefer a solution in xetex. Splitting up the node into a Japanese and an English node might work this time but maybe next time the lines are mixed, so I'm looking for a more general solution.

Maybe *A* doesn't have a font installed that *B* does? But it's only an 's' that gets replaced, all other characters are fine...

**Update**
The printer does not print on empty business cards as I imagined, but on a large sheet, which is then cut, so I could not get my one debug card.
But I'll take to heart to never use minimal, but article instead!

Comment: Please don't use `minimal` for examples - it is not suitable. I assume you aren't using this in your real document. Are all the `s`s replaced? All `s`s of a kind? All `s`s of a kind on certain lines? Are all fonts embedded? What kind of printer? Which driver? And which printing programme?

Comment: When the PDF is printed, assuming it looks OK on screen then, choosing 'print as image' (or equivalent option) can help. I've not seen this problem with good quality printers, but crappier printers with crappy drivers, certainly. Another question: is the Japanese font embedded in full? How much memory does the printer have? I *think* - and this is a guess - that some printers will start cutting out font stuff if there's too much. However, in those cases, I've seen it miss characters or replace with (presumably) the built-in defaults.

Comment: A very naive thought: does replacing @ by {@} improve the situation? I apologize in advance if this is nonsense.

Comment: @cfr I *do* use `minimal` in the real document! I figured that because I do everything in `tikzpicture` it's the least efford.
There was only one `s` in the whole document. I'll use more in the debug document.
As for embedding, I didn't do anything but run `xelatex mydoc.tex`. properies fonts says `All fonts are either standard or embedded`. Fonts in question are `LMRoman10-Regular-Identity-H` and `FandolSong-Regular-Identity-H`.
I'll ask about the printer, but I doubt they know about their driver.

Comment: `minimal` isn't suitable. You do not get a standard font configuration if you use this class. Lots of the standard font stuff is missing. It should never be used for a real document.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue cannot be reproduced.